# How to prove this integral inequality??

Tags: integration, inequality

Here this problem:
$$
\begin{align*}\int^{a+1}_{-1}\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a-x+1)\Gamma(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x>2^a>\int^{a+\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a-x+1)\Gamma(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x\end{align*}
$$

The source is to "serialize" the binomial theorem.And while the above inequality is a special case, the following is a more general integral inequality:

$$
\begin{align*}
\forall k>0,a>-1,f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{k^x}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(a-x+1)}&x\in(-1,a+1)\\0&x\in\{-1,a+1\}\end{cases} \end{align*}
$$
Try to prove the following integral inequality:  $\begin{align*}\\
\int_{-1}^{a+1}f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x>\frac{(k+1)^{a}}{\Gamma(a+1)} \\
\end{align*}$

And when $k$ is equal to $1$,there's a special inequality:$\begin{align*}\\
\frac{(k+1)^{a}}{\Gamma(a+1)}>\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{a+\frac{1}{2}}f(x)\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}$

So that's our initial inequality.
The source of the problem is to "serialize" the binomial theorem, so I found this integral inequality, please tell me how to prove this integral inequality? Thank you for your answers!